# Keycloak authentication using google id Token / access Token

Tags: android, flutter, keycloak, google-signin, keycloak-rest-api

I'm currently developing a **Flutter application** with Keycloak as authenticating server using [Open_id](https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client) flutter package.

I have implemented email & password signin using  [Keycloak restApi for username & password sign in](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/01/29/api-login-and-jwt-token-generation-using-keycloak#test_your_new_client)

I need to add google signIn in my app. But it open custom webview for google signin.

**Google signin flow** :
Flutter App trigger Open id - authenticator with keycloak credential

--> opens custom webview

--> keycloak signIn page

--> redirects to google account signin

--> keycloak verification page

--> closes webview and return keycloak token (contains user info).

and some time the custom Webview tab doesn't closes automatically.

I have used [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) to generate idToken and accessToken. and in backend used the google restApi ('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?id_token=) to get user info.

Is there any **restApi** for Keycloak sign in using **Google idToken/AccessToken** .

or any other way of authenticate keycloak using custom token ?, so i can set google api as verification url for authenticating.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: yes, but not exactly. I just changed the flow,1. Added deeplink functionality using ui_links package. 2. Set the deeplink uri as redirect url in Keycloak console. 3. Using url_launcher pushed the keycloak google sign url with redirect url as deeplink url to browser app(not a custom webview/tab). 

So, after that google sign in will redirect to keyclaok, it will authenticate google idToken, and redirects to deeplink url with auth-code and state.

Parses the auth code with uni_links and sends the  code to backend via rest and receives the user info, access token, etc

Comment: thanks we will give it a try